# MYSQL select to get Consecutive Day Count user wise where the value is lesser than previous day value

Tags: select, gaps-and-islands, mysql-8.0

**MySql V 8.0**

Question: How to write MySQL select to get Consecutive Day Count where the weight value is lesser than the previous day weight value user wise and break when no longer consecutive or weight value is same or greater than the previous day weight value of the same user.

```
create table userData (recordDate ,userName varchar(100), weight FLOAT);
```

```
insert into userData (recordDate, userName, weight)
values
    ('2020/8/1','Chris', 78),
    ('2021/8/2','Chris', 77),
    ('2021/8/3','Chris', 76),
    ('2021/8/1','Aamir', 78),
    ('2021/8/2','Aamir', 77),
    ('2021/8/1','Alex', 78),
    ('2021/8/2','Alex', 77),
    ('2021/8/3','Alex', 76),
    ('2021/8/5','Chris', 78),
    ('2021/8/6','Chris', 77),
    ('2021/8/7','Chris', 76),
    ('2021/8/8','Chris', 75),
    ('2021/8/8','Aamir', 78), 
    ('2021/8/8','Alex', 78),
    ('2021/8/9','John', 78),
    ('2021/8/1','Ali', 78),
    ('2021/8/10','Chris', 78);
```

**The expected output is**

```
| userName | streakDays | startingDate | endingDate |  
| -------- | ---------- | ------------ | ---------- |  
| Alex     | 3          | 2021-08-01   | 2021-08-03 | 
| Chris    | 3          | 2021-08-06   | 2021-08-08 | 
| Aamir    | 2          | 2021-08-01   | 2021-08-02 | 
| Ali      | 1          | 2021-08-01   | 2021-08-01 | 
| John     | 1          | 2021-08-09   | 2021-08-09 |
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem resolved with the following query**:

```sql
select
   streakBreakersRemoved.userName,
   streakBreakersRemoved.streakDays,
   streakBreakersRemoved.startingDate,
   streakBreakersRemoved.endingDate 
from
   (
      select
         userName,
         count(*) as streakDays,
         min(recordDate) as startingDate,
         max(recordDate) as endingDate,
         row_number() over (partition by userName 
      order by
         count(*) desc) as seqNum 
      from
         (
            select
               initailRecords.*,
               row_number() over (partition by userName 
            order by
               recordDate) as initialSeqNum 
            from
               (
                  select
                     userData.*,
                     lag(weight) over (partition by userName 
                  order by
                     recordDate) as previousWeight 
                  from
                     userData 
               )
               initailRecords 
            where
               if(previousWeight is null || previousWeight > weight, 1, 0) = 1 
         )
         recordsWithSeqNum 
      group by
         userName,
         to_days(recordDate) - initialSeqNum 
   )
   streakBreakersRemoved 
where
   seqNum = 1 
order by
   streakDays desc;
```

**Would appreciate if anyone would like to optimize the above query.**

Answer (score 0):

According To Your data inserted in the table , This Select Query Works Fine

```
select userName as un , 
count((select recordDate WHERE userName = un)) as strekdays,
(select recordDate FROM userdata WHERE userName = un limit 1)  as startdate ,
(select recordDate FROM userdata WHERE userName = un order by recordDate DESC limit 1)  as enddate
from userdata
group by userName
```

And It Gives Output Like

| userName | streakDays | startingDate | endingDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aamir | 3 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-08-08 |
| Alex | 4 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-08-08 |
| Ali | 1 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-08-01 |
| Chris | 8 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-08-10 |
| John | 1 | 2021-08-09 | 2021-08-09 |

Let me know If this Works FOr You or not !

Comment: unfortunately not, it does not work for me as, for example, Chris in your result shows 8 but it should be 3 as there is no 2021/8/4 for Chris in the data which breaks the Consecutive Day streak. The expected result is also given in my question and it should match exactly.